What is the difference between model, modelData and required property?
I have a model that I assign to a delegate in qml, what is the difference in passing properties:
model
ListView {
    model: myModel
    delegate: Label {
        text: model.name
    }
}

modelData
ListView {
    model: myModel
    delegate: Label {
        text: modelData.name
    }
}

required property
ListView {
    model: myModel
    delegate: Label {
        required property string name
        text: name
    }
}

Also I noticed that if I use the QAbstrastListModel then only the last option will do, why this?

Have you read the documentation here?

In all three cases you are just setting the Label's text property.
There's no difference other than the source of text.
QAbstrastListModel should work in the first two cases as well as long as it contains the 'name' property/data.
Share a minimal-reproducible-example if you can't get it working.
